# Sitecore NVelocity implementation

Tags: presentation

Looking into some existing code that uses the Sitecore NVelocity implementation.
Anyone with some experience on this?

```csharp
string Header = VelocityHelper.Evaluate(VContext, SpecificEnum.Header, "SpecificHeader");
```

classnames and variables were chosen for sport :)

A good link to some insightfull documentation would be very much welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

The Evaluate method processes the velocity template and returns the rendering result.

```
public static string Evaluate(VelocityContext context, string template, string logName)
  {
     StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
     Velocity.Evaluate(context, result, logName, template);
     return result.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
```

Below is the description of its parameters:

context - Populated velocity context;

Template - Velocity template to process 
logName - Name that will be used to log the event

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20NVelocity/Set%20Default%20Date.aspx

Method with 4 parameters has next definition.

```
evaluate( Context context, Writer out, String logTag, String instring )

evaluate( Context context, Writer writer, String logTag, InputStream instream )
```

These methods will render the input, in either the form of String or InputStream to an output Writer, using a Context that you provide. This is a very convenienient method to use for token replacement of strings, or if you keep 'templates' of VTL-containing content in a place like a database or other non-file storage, or simply generate such dynamically.

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html

Comment: I got that far indeed. In this instance,the template (or later instring) is a reference to a Sitecore template field instance which I find weird. I get that the context gets populated with variables that aim to replace tokens or placeholders. However, I am at a miss as to where the generated HTML is comming from...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation I use in one of our API's.

```
public virtual string MergeTemplate(string template, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(template, nameof(template));
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(data, nameof(data));

        try
        {
            Velocity.Init();
            VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

            foreach (string key in data.Keys)
            {
                context.Put(key, data[key]);
            }

            return VelocityHelper.Evaluate(context, template, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"Failed to merge the e-mail template: {Environment.NewLine}{template}", ex, this);
        }

        return template;
    }
```

You pass in the template as string (containing the tokens to replace or logic to execute) and a dictionary where the key equals the token in the template and the object the actual object that's going to do something.

Comment: HI Drazen, the existing code that I got has a Sitecore GUID as template value... Turns out that this GUID refers to a template field instance... No idea how this was meant to work then...